How is it possible that Minecraft save files are so small?
I want to make a game almost like Minecraft using Three.js, but something that stumps me is how you have over 100,000 blocks in a world and the save files are not that big in size. How does Mojang make Minecraft world save files? (Any version of Minecraft works for me)
For instance, there is this unicorn world my little sister downloaded a long, long time ago for Bedrock edition, and it's just a pink world with tons of ice cream statues, rainbows, castles, Unicorns, and other stuff like that. It goes on for pretty much 2000 blocks in every direction (not including the Y axis) and that world is only 6 MB. How is this possible?

examine the open source Minetest ... https://www.minetest.net/

Have all of those blocks in this world been hand-crafted, or is there some amount of generated terrain (even if generated with modified settings, like replacing normal stone/dirt/grass with other block types, or generating unusual terrain shapes and distributions)?

I think most of it was hand-crafted. Once you reach the end of the pink world, the world goes back to the normal trees and villages. If you own Bedrock edition, look up Unicorn Island in the Minecraft store. I think it costs Minecoins, so you can just look at the images they have (It might also have a video link while you look into it).

@jsotola Woah, this is interesting. I see it has Minecraft images and other Minecraft stuff, so is it legal?

the terrain is probably generated by an algorithm ... possibly using Perlin noise

Some games I looked at used XML, JSON, or their own "text scripts"; which when compressed; takes maybe 10%. If they use "binary files" with "bit flags" and one byte codes, it winds up taking maybe even less space. The form a "world" is saved in doesn't have to match what's in memory; it just needs a form that can be saved and restored from.

And that is probably why it takes some time for a chunk to load in when you travel. It's a clever way of doing it. It's kinda like compressing a file to a zip file.

You may also be interested in How is world data stored in Minecraft? and specifications of Minecraft's save file format. They do, in fact, use zlib compression similar to a zip file.

Nice. I just did a quick search of zilb, and I was not aware that Playstations, Xbox, and Wiis did this. That is awesome. I'll have to look into this some more, because I know size can be an issue.

There are a few things going on here:
6MB is bigger than you think
A megabyte is over one million bytes. A million is a huge number. The text of almost any novel would fit inside of a single megabyte.
Unless they are doing something irresponsible with their data (like JSON.stringifying the entire game state), save game data for most games aught to fit within one megabyte.
Minecraft is not like "most" games, though, which brings us to...
Sparse Voxel Octrees
(I don't know if this exact algorithm is the one Minecraft uses, but it almost certainly uses something like this)
A Sparse Voxel Octree is a data structure which can efficiently store a 3D voxel map, assuming that groups of similar voxels are often clumped together. For example, in most Minecraft worlds, there are large sections of contiguous open air, then a dirt layer (with occasional other things), then the underground, which is mostly stone (with occasional other things). These layers are not flat, but they're still thick enough to compress.
The algorithm works something like the following:
Subdivide the world into chunks of some standardized top-level size, such that all 3 dimensions are powers of 2. (This may be different from Minecraft chunks which are 16xNx16)
For each chunk, write the following data in a binary format:

If the entire chunk is all one identical material, write a 0x0 nybble followed by the identifier of that material.
If the entire chunk is something for which a copy exists verbatim previously in the same file, write a 0x1 nybble followed by the index of the copy.
Otherwise, write a 0x2 nybble followed by its contents, described as 8 chunks, each of which is 1/2 the dimension of the larger chunk.

Additional chunk types could be defined for other common, repeating patterns. For example, a chunk which contains exactly 2 block types, split across an axis-aligned plane could be a chunk type (which would easily compress some features, like the borders between the dirt and stone layers, or the walls of a house).
Using this algorithm (or one like it), most voxel worlds (those which are not just random noise) can easily be compressed into significantly smaller than 1-byte-per-block.

I cannot really say how it is done, however I would do it next way:

Create and store a map of all of the blocks which exist in the world to indices (2 bytes for index should be enough).
Store each chunk/region in separate file with file name containing it's coordinates
Each file would contain all the blocks info in sequential order with no delimiters. So for example block at x,y,z in this region would be at (x*height*depth + y*depth + z) position in the region file, where height is region height and depth is region depth.

As soon as file contains only sequence of 2 bytes per block - chunk 16*16*384 blocks (98.304) would take only 196.608 bytes. 10*10 chunks would take only ~19MB.
Obviously there could be used some compression algorithms on top of that which would allow you to reduce the size of the region file even more.

Compression files, I didn't think of that. Maybe that's why it takes a bit for a chunk to load when you travel on (Especially when gliding not knowing when or where the mountain is going to load in. )
